# Python Flask-socketio not connecting

Tags: python, flask, websocket, wsgi, flask-socketio

I'm using flask-socketio to send data between a python web server and a client web page.

Server Code :

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO,emit

app=Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder="static/")
socketio=SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("socket connected")

if __name__=='__main__':
  socketio.run(app)
```

Javascript client code :

```js
const socket=io('http://localhost:5000');
socket.on('connect',()=>{
  console.log('connected!');
}
```

Now,when I run it locally on my computer,it works fine.
But when I deployed it on [Glitch](https://glitch.com) and ran it, It gave me few warnings as :

```
Serving Flask app (lazy loading)
Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: on
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Restarting with stat WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved performance.
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 327-937-508
```

And my code wasn't working. I was able to open index.html but the console didn't log "socket connected". Also, none of my other socket emits were working.

After going through a few stack overflow questions, I changed my server code to :

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO,emit
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer


app=Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder="static/")

http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()

socketio=SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print("socket connected")

if __name__=='__main__':
  socketio.run(app)
```

This fixed the warnings but everything still doesn't work.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So I got it working

The problem was with client side being `io('http://localhost:5000')` , since the client is no longer running locally.

I fixed it by changing client to `io()` and server to `socketio.run(app,port=3000)`